# Laravel in Google Cloud

Tags: mysql, laravel, google-app-engine

I have a Laravel project in Google Cloud. But when I try to log in, I get a timeout error for MySQL.
NOTE: my database is on another external server so I am connecting through an IP address in the `DH_HOST` variable.
Inside the Google Cloud terminal I can easily access the database through:

```
mysql -h xx -u xx -p
```

Below is my error log:

```
Illuminate \ Database \ QueryException (2002)
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection timed out (SQL: select * from `users` where `email` = *** limit 1)
```

Comment: I think you have added wrong DB connection details please debug by `dd(DB::connection());`

Comment: There is a [Community Tutorial for using Laravel on App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/run-laravel-on-appengine-flexible). Perhaps you can go through it and tell us more about where the problem is arising.